# how to customize plot using xarray faceting option

Tags: python-xarray, facet-grid

I am trying to overlay a contour plot overtop of a facetted plot in xarray using the fg.map function. I am trying to overlay a contour plot (the same time slice, repeated on each panel) on top of each facetted panels. However, the final line does not seem to be working.

The code is:

```
fg = moc10_H11.MOC.plot(col="time", col_wrap=5, yincrease = False)

# Use this to plot contours on each panel
fg.map_dataarray(
    xr.plot.contour, x="lat_aux_grid", y="moc_z", colors="k", levels=13, add_colorbar=False, yincrease = False,
)

# Add overlaying contours from the PI climatology dataset.
fg.map(lambda: plt.gca().contour(moc_PI_clim.MOC.isel(time=0), colors="grey"))
```

[image: Plot that is generated. It lacks the contours from the final fg.map call]

Does anyone see what I am not doing correctly?  Could this have to do with the fact that the time slices in the faceted plot do not match the one I call in fg.map?

If I try to plot just that one line I get the following image (which is what I want overlain on each panel, except for the yaxis not being reversed here).

```
plt.contour(moc_PI_clim.MOC.isel(time=0), colors="grey")
```

[image: Climatology contours alone]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `plt.gca()` returns the current/last referenced axis in every iteration of the loop. can you just loop over the axes with `for ax in fg.axes.flat` and plot on the ax object?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  In the end, I opted to do a standard subplot without xarray's faceting.  It seemed to me more straightforward and easier to customize.